# Reinstalling baseboards in front of utility flue or gas chimney

Tags: plaster, baseboard, patching-drywall

I'm replacing the baseboards in one of rooms of the 2nd floor of my 1907 duplex and found the gas chimney running up through the 3 story building. The old plaster was crumbling across the base of the wall so I was thinking of repairing it with a coat of durabond or drywall. (I haven't plastered before). Is it safe or recommended to cover the utility flue or should I keep the area clear and just use something like liquid nails to hold down my baseboard/base shoe? Looks like the previous owners attached it with glue but not entirely sure what's the safest route here.

[image: chimney]

Comment: Personally, I don't see a problem.  But how will you mount your base there?

Comment: Yeah that’s one of my issues since there’s no framing around the chimney. I’m thinking of putting down a layer of some concrete adhesive and then nailing the baseboards into that so I don’t hit the chimney?